# Count the number of times a number is repeating in a vector

Tags: matlab, count, numbers

I have created a vector containing zeros and 1's using the following command in a for loop.

```
G(:,i)=rand(K,1)<rand;
```

Since this is part of a larger problem at a particular stage I need to count the number of 1's that are present in each column.

I have tried to find the count using a for loop which is very messy and takes too long. 
I found that histc can be used for this but I get an error

```
 histc(G(:,1),1)
 First input must be non-sparse numeric array.
```

Is there a better way to do this or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a matrix `G` containing zeroes and ones, and you want to know how many ones are in each column, all you need is [SUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html):

```
nZeroes = sum(G);
```

This will give you a vector containing a total for each column in `G`.

Comment: @thanks gnovice since i am adding columns to the G after every iteration and need to find the number of 1's to the latest iteration i am using the above answer slightly modified sum(G(:,i)

Comment: @BhavyaPH: In that case, you could also use the function [NNZ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nnz.html).